# Codename One Drag & Drop blackens dialog background

Tags: background, drag-and-drop, codenameone

I'm developing an app that uses drag & drop operations. The drag & drop part includes four containers as drop targets and two draggable labels.

The app works as expected in the simulator, but when I install it on my Android phone, the background of the dialog (otherwise white) turns black for a swift moment as soon as the draggable components (labels) are released (then gets back to the original light color).

In the theme builder, I have set the background of the dialog to an almost white color (unselected, selected, pressed, disabled), but that doesn't show any effect.

Is there any turnaround to keep the background color stable? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant code excerpt:

```
        Dialog dialog_W1 = new Dialog();
        dialog_W1.setScrollableY(true);
        dialog_W1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(2));
        dialog_W1.setScrollableY(true);
        dialog_W1.setTitle("Acerte o bichinho");              

        Image img_Cat = Image.createImage("/cat.png");
        ScaleImageLabel label_Scaled_Image = new ScaleImageLabel(img_Cat);
        label_Scaled_Image.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);        
        label_Scaled_Image.setUIID("NewLabel");        

        Label label_1 = new Label("ga");
        Label label_2 = new Label("to");

        label_1.setUIID("LabelWord");
        label_2.setUIID("LabelWord");

        label_1.setDraggable(true);
        label_2.setDraggable(true);

        Container c_1 = new Container();
        Container c_2 = new Container();
        Container c_3 = new Container();
        Container c_4 = new Container();

        c_1.setDropTarget(true);
        c_2.setDropTarget(true);
        c_3.setDropTarget(true);
        c_4.setDropTarget(true);

        c_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(2));
        c_2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(2));
        c_3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(2));
        c_4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(2));

        c_1.setUIID("Container_1");
        c_2.setUIID("Container_1");
        c_3.setUIID("Container_2");
        c_4.setUIID("Container_2");

        c_3.add(label_2);
        c_4.add(label_1);

        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,2);       
        Container container_0 = new Container(gl);    
        container_0.add(c_1);
        container_0.add(c_2);
        container_0.add(c_3);
        container_0.add(c_4);                  

        ArrayList <Container> list_Containers = new ArrayList<>(); 
        list_Containers.add(c_1);
        list_Containers.add(c_2);
        list_Containers.add(c_3);
        list_Containers.add(c_4);

        ArrayList <Label> list_Labels = new ArrayList<>();
        list_Labels.add(label_1);
        list_Labels.add(label_2);

        for (Label label : list_Labels) {
            label.addDragOverListener(new ActionListener() {                
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                    for (Container c : list_Containers) {
                        int int_C = c.getComponentCount();
                        if (int_C == 1) {
                            c.setDropTarget(false);
                        } else if (int_C == 0) {
                            c.setDropTarget(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });  
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest showing the Dialog as a modless dialog instead of using the `show` method use `showModless()` or similar.

Odd things like this can happen because of the EDT nesting inherent in modal dialogs, normally we don't recommend using dialog for anything more than simple notifications. When we use drag and drop from a dialog like component we use `InteractionDialog`.

Comment: Shai, tried both suggestions: showModeless() makes the screen blink transparent (instead of black, as before) after the component is dropped. To try the InteractionDialog I have used the example from  https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/InteractionDialog.html , but the window has a strange light-gray overlay both in the simulator and the installed app ..

Comment: For the InteractionDialog, a gray overlay screen stays even after calling dlg.dispose(), covering all components of the initial screen..

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it, this only happens on the device right? Which Android version are we talking about? Did you test on more than one device?

Comment: Shai, I started a new project and the gray overlay wasn't there anymore. I will go ahead with InterActionDialog. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Something I observed is that when I style the component Container in the theme manager, the background color overlays the whole InterActionDialog Screen. I don't know if this is intended....

Comment: Don't style the `Container` UIID. It's a special case we rely on. `Container` must be transparent with 0 padding/margin always

Comment: Valuable clarification. Thanks for the additional info.